# VBA - Execute or Run .bat File Inside Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have been attempting to automate a series of administrative events for some of the users where I work by creating scripts and macro's and so on..

These scripts and macros work great, however, I would like to make a the process even easier for the users by running a single batch file that will systematically execute the scripts and macros.

The batch file I currently have, calls all the scripts one by one, and the very last script opens one of the xlsm workbooks which contains a few macro's in it - and here is where the issue is - There are still scripts to be executed but they can only be executed once this workbook has executed all its macros.

So my initial thought was to test if the workbook is open, if it is, delay the execution of the next script by a minute or so, then test again and again... until it is closed.. Then I thought perhaps it would be easier to execute the next set of scripts (also in a batch file) from within a macro.

So, I have this code:

```
Sub Run_BAT()

    Set obj = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    obj.Run Chr(34) & "X:\Test\" & "Termination Reports Scripts\" & "Execute_Terminations.bat" & Chr(34), 0, True

    Set obj = Nothing

End Sub
```

Which gives me an error:

> Permission Denied

Then there's this code:

```
Sub WriteAndRunBatFile()

Call Shell("X:\Test\Termination Reports Scripts\Execute_Terminations.bat")

End Sub
```

Which gives me the error:

> Invalid procedure call

Any and every single code sample that contains the "Shell" command gives this error.

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
Call Shell("cmd.exe /C /K " & "ChDir X:\Test\Termination_Reports_Scripts && Execute_Terminations.bat", vbNormalFocus)
```

And yes, check permissions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately I still get the same error - Invalid procedure call.

Comment: Did you try executing from command line first to ensure permissions?

Comment: When you say to ensure permissions, do you mean able to access the location? If so, I am able to run a batch file or script file directly in this location to extract from this location.

Comment: I mean can you run "ChDir X:\Test\Termination_Reports_Scripts && Execute_Terminations.bat"  in the CLI?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I have no clue.. I typed "ChDir X:\Test\Termination_Reports_Scripts && Execute_Terminations.bat" in cmd and got an error: filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.. Then without the quotes I get the error .bat is not recognized

Comment: if you do cd X:\Test\Termination_Reports_Scripts first does it change to the specified directory?

Comment: Yes it does @QHarr

Comment: Once it has changed directory can you then run  Execute_Terminations.bat   ?

Comment: I tried typing this in cmd start "" /D X:\Test\Termination_Reports_Scripts\ /W Execute_Terminations.bat and nothing happens. Doesn't fail but it doesn't do anything either.

Comment: I mean if you run the two command separately. So first the change dir command which we know works. And then when you have changed directory execute the second command. It the second doesn't do anything then it is the .bat that needs debugging potentially.

Answer (score 1):

Place your path to bat file in quotes:

`Call Shell("cmd /c ""S:/somebatfile.bat""", vbNormalFocus)`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately I still get the same error - Invalid procedure call.

Answer (score 1):

My theory is you're missing a reference in your application to the Windows Script Host Object Model.

In the VBA Editor, go to Tools, References, make sure that one's ticked.

It's not ticked by default for security reasons - imagine unintended access to the command prompt in every instance of a Microsoft Office application...!

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. I unfortunately don't work in the job that required this anymore lol. So I will remember for next time! And yes, your are correct... It would be a HUGE security issue. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hey, no problem - sorry to hear about that. I put it up there in spite of the time difference because if I was searching for the answer, I'd want someone to have posted it here :) Thanks for the kudos, and coming back after so long!

Answer (score 0):

(1) Check permission of user of that `X` directory.
(2) Test the code by removing spaces from directory name.

Also try the following code ***(Please try it by removing spaces from directory name).***

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Call Shell("CMD.EXE /C " & "X:\Test\Termination_Reports_Scripts\Execute_Terminations.bat")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately I still get the same error - Invalid procedure call.