# Unable to execute bat file from macro

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file

I have a batch file which I want to execute from an excel button click. 
I can execute batch file independently from cmd window but my macro code always throw error, my macro code is here:

This always lead to error run-time error '5' invalid procedure call or argument.

I tried many ways but still no luck, any luck.

I have already tried with paths handling but still no luck.

Macro:

```
Private Sub update_Click()
    Dim ret As Integer
    ret = Shell("D:\Automation\Main.bat", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Batch file:

```
REM remove files generated Start
del D:\Automation\results* /Q
REM remove files generated End

SET y=%date:~10,4%
SET m=%date:~4,2%
SET d=%date:~7,2%
SET h=%time:~0,2%
SET mm=%time:~3,2%
SET s=%time:~6,2%
SET resultfilename=D:\Automation\results_%y%%m%%d%_%h%%mm%%s%.txt

call ./CheckBuildStatus.bat 17 %resultfilename%
call ./CheckBuildStatus.bat 18 %resultfilename%

REM remove files generated Start
del D:\Automation\webcontent.* /Q
REM remove files generated End
```

I expect the batch should run when I click on the button in excel by macro.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9403341/4650297) help?  Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49918987/4650297)? Or any of [these](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=run%20bat%20file%20from%20vba)?

Comment: What other ways have you tried? Besides path handling?

Comment: Well, do you really need a batch file after all? Anyway, I would definitely build the date/time string in VBA rather than batch, because that is way easier and more reliable as not locale-dependent since there are such data types...